# What is the difference between decodeObject(forKey:) & decodeObjectForKey(_:)

Tags: swift, nscoding

Here are two examples in use.

```
// The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
    os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    return nil
}

// Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
let photo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
```

Comment: Have you tried using both or are you just asking about them? Only one works depending on your version of Swift/iOS/macOS.

Answer (score 1):

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` is originally a bridged objective c class so you can use

`decodeObjectForKey(_:)` In swift <3.0

and

`decodeObject(forKey:)` In swift >= 3

internally they are the same thing , it's syntax changing  ,  have a look to this [Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80033)

Comment: Perfect thank you, I'm new to programming and I anticipated it might just be a change in syntax but I was not sure.